# How to turn off transparency on mesh, cycles render

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, transparency

recently I happened to make an object transparent by luck, I don't remember how I did it. Now I am trying to figure out how to reverse the object back to its solid state. The viewport is set to texture which should show the mesh. How do I make the object visible again?

I deleted a transparent material and assigned new material. That didn't work. I also checked if transparency mode was turned off in the background image and render settings.

[image]

Comment: Check the maximum draw type in the object tab of the properties editor. It might be set to 'wire'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you set the *Maximum Draw Type* to *Wire* on that mesh. Set it to *Solid* or *Textured* (the latter is the default).

[image]

I can't be absolutely certain that this is it, as your screenshot doesn't show that part of the UI, but since you're not in wireframe viewport shading, I'm guessing that this is the problem.

Comment: Yeah that was the problem, I forgot about that. Thank you.